# How does fulfilment work in AWS Lambda functionchatbot

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

**I am writing the lambda function to check the name and NRIC of the patients, validation functions are working, however, the fulfillment part was not functioning. when data is validated and to return to the close function, the message is not displayed. Anyone please help, thank you.**

following is my lambda function and respective methods

```
import math
import datetime
import time
import os
import logging


"""--- logger create log object which stores all infor---"""
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def get_slots(intent_request):
    return intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']


def elicit_slot(session_attributes, intent_name, slots, slot_to_elicit, message):
    return {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'ElicitSlot',
            'intentName': intent_name,
            'slots': slots,
            'slotToElicit': slot_to_elicit,
            'message': message
        }
    }


def close(session_attributes, fulfillment_state, message):
    response = {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Close',
            'fulfillmentState': fulfillment_state,
            'message': message
        }
    }

    return response


def delegate(session_attributes, slots):
    return {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Delegate',
            'slots': slots
        }
    }


"""--- Helper function---"""


def build_validation_result(is_valid, violated_slot, message_content):
    if message_content is None:
        return {
            "isValid": is_valid,
            "violatedSlot": violated_slot,
        }

    return {
        'isValid': is_valid,
        'violatedSlot': violated_slot,
        'message': {'contentType': 'PlainText', 'content': message_content}
    }

def validate_postalcode(patientAddressCode):
    postalCodes = ['111111', '222222', '333333']
    if patientAddressCode is not None and patientAddressCode not in postalCodes:
        return False
    else:
        True

def validate_nric(patientNRIC):
    prefixList = ["s", "t", "f", "g"]
    # if len(patientNRIC) == 9 and patientNRIC[0] in prefixList and patientNRIC[8].isalpha():
    #     return build_validation_result(True, None, None)
    if len(patientNRIC) != 9 or patientNRIC[0].lower() not in prefixList or patientNRIC[
        8].isalpha() == False:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def validate_name(patientName):
    names = ['john', 'jane', 'jenny']
    if patientName is not None and patientName.lower() not in names:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def validate_credentials(patientName,patientNRIC):
    if patientName is not None:
        if not validate_name(patientName):
            return build_validation_result(False, 'patientName',
                                       'Sorry we cannot find {}'.format(patientName))

    if patientNRIC is not None:
        if not validate_nric(patientNRIC):
            return build_validation_result(
            False,
            "patientNRIC",
            'NRIC should have total of 9 characters, the first letter should include [s,t,f,g],and the last letter should be alphabet. Please check and try again'.format(
                patientNRIC))

    # patientAddressCode = str(patientAddressCode)
    # postalCodes = ['111111', '222222', '333333']
    # if patientAddressCode is not None and patientAddressCode not in postalCodes:
    #     return build_validation_result(False, 'postalCode',
    #                                    'Sorry {} you have enter the wrong code'.format(patientAddressCode))
    return build_validation_result(True, None, None)




    """ --- Intents --- """


def dispatch(intent_request):
    """
    Called when the user specifies an intent for this bot.
    """

    logger.debug(
        'dispatch userId={}, intentName={}'.format(intent_request['userId'], intent_request['currentIntent']['name']))

    intent_name = intent_request['currentIntent']['name']

    # Dispatch to your bot's intent handlers
    if intent_name == 'Authentication':
        return authentication(intent_request)

    raise Exception('Intent with name ' + intent_name + ' not supported')


def authentication(intent_request):
    """
    Performs dialog management and fulfillment for ordering flowers.
    Beyond fulfillment, the implementation of this intent demonstrates the use of the elicitSlot dialog action
    in slot validation and re-prompting.
    """

    slots = get_slots(intent_request)

    patientName = slots["patientName"]
    patientNRIC = slots["patientNRIC"]
    # patientAddressCode = slots["patientAddressCode"]

    source = intent_request['invocationSource']

    if source == 'DialogCodeHook':
        # Perform basic validation on the supplied input slots.
        # Use the elicitSlot dialog action to re-prompt for the first violation detected.

        validation_result = validate_credentials(patientName,patientNRIC)
        if not validation_result['isValid']:
            slots[validation_result['violatedSlot']] = None
            return elicit_slot(intent_request['sessionAttributes'],
                               intent_request['currentIntent']['name'],
                               slots,
                               validation_result['violatedSlot'],
                               validation_result['message'])
        output_session_attributes = intent_request['sessionAttributes'] if intent_request[
                                                                               'sessionAttributes'] is not None else {}
        return delegate(output_session_attributes, get_slots(intent_request))

        # patientNRIC=str(patientNRIC).lower()

    return close(intent_request['sessionAttributes'],
                 'Fulfilled',
                 {'contentType': 'PlainText',
                  'content': 'Thank you {},Your NRIC is {}, we have verified your credentials'.format(patientName,patientNRIC)})


    """ --- Main handler --- """


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """
    Route the incoming request based on intent.
    The JSON body of the request is provided in the event slot.
    """
    # By default, treat the user request as coming from the America/New_York time zone.
    os.environ["TZ"] = "Asia/Singapore"
    time.tzset()
    logger.debug('event.bot.name={}'.format(event['bot']['name']))
    logger.debug(event)
    return dispatch(event)
```

Comment: That is a lot of code to look through... might you be more specific, or offer any more details?

Not an AWS expert at all, so perhaps they are co-opting language in a way I am unfamiliar with... but, when I read "lambda" I think, "anonymous function" -- of which I see none in this snippet.  Am I missing something?

Comment: hahaha, thank your for taking the time to answer this qn. The lambda function is not the anonymous fun that we usually referring to when writing codes. It is related to AWS chatbot.